# WordPress - User Query - Order by Meta Value

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use a WordPress User Query to create a list of users that is ordered by a custom meta value.  Its a simple numeric value, going from 1 to 100, so 1 needs to be displayed first, 100 last, etc.

This is my attempt, which has failed miserably:

```
<?php

    $args  = array(
        'role' => 'Author',
        'meta_key' => 'order-number',
        'orderby' => 'order-number',
        'order' => 'asc',  
    );

$wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$authors = $wp_user_query->get_results();

if (!empty($authors))
{
    echo '<div style="float:left;">';
    foreach ($authors as $author)
    {
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
        echo '<div class="post team-member"><div class="image">';
        echo get_avatar( $author_info->ID, 91 );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="content"><div class="title"><a href="/author/' . $author_info->user_login . '">' . $author_info->user_firstname . ' ' . $author_info->user_lastname . '</a></div>';
        echo '' . substr( get_the_author_meta('user_description',$author_info->ID) , 0 , 100 ) . '...'; 
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}

    ?>
```

I think the problem is that wp_user_query does not support custom fields in orderby - so I need a solution that works around this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The orderby parameter can only accept possible values of 'login' (default), 'nicename', 'email', 'url', and 'registered'.

A dirty fix would be something like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb; //Ignore this line if you're not within a function
$order = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key='order-number' ORDER BY meta_value ASC", "ARRAY_N");
$authors = array();
foreach($order as $aid)
    $authors[] = new WP_User($aid[0]);

if (!empty($authors))
{
    echo '<div style="float:left;">';
    foreach ($authors as $author)
    {
        $author_info = get_userdata($author->ID);
        echo '<div class="post team-member"><div class="image">';
        echo get_avatar( $author_info->ID, 91 );
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="content"><div class="title"><a href="/author/' . $author_info->user_login . '">' . $author_info->user_firstname . ' ' . $author_info->user_lastname . '</a></div>';
        echo '' . substr( get_the_author_meta('user_description',$author_info->ID) , 0 , 100 ) . '...'; 
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
} else {
    echo 'No authors found';
}
```

This is largely untested, so I can't guarantee this will work straight out of the gate, but it should get you started.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @maiorano84 Thanks so much I've spent hours trying to figure this out and this has done just the trick. One part I'm still struggling with is restricting this to only users with the role 'Subscriber'?

Comment: @tbwcf - That information is best handled after the WP_User object has been instantiated. To limit the Author array to only subscribers, you can do something like this: `foreach($order as $aid){ $u = new WP_User($aid[0]); if(in_array("subscriber", $u->roles)) $authors[] = $u; }`

Comment: @maiorano84 that's perfect, thank you I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

// prepare arguments this is your query.
$args = array(
'meta_key' => 'last_name',
'query_id' => 'wps_last_name',
);

// Create the WP_User_Query object
$author_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

?>

Add following lines to functions.php file

<?php

add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wps_pre_user_query' );
/*
* Modify the WP_User_Query appropriately
*
* Checks for the proper query to modify and changes the default user_login for $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value
*
* @param WP_User_Query Object $query User Query object before query is executed
*/
function wps_pre_user_query( &$query ) {
global $wpdb;
if ( isset( $query->query_vars['query_id'] ) && 'wps_last_name' == $query->query_vars['query_id'] )
$query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', "$wpdb->usermeta.meta_value", $query->query_orderby );
}
?>
```